# TypeScript: Cannot find name of variable (set in conditional statement)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements, javascript-scope

I'm trying to assign the value of a variable based on a condition inside an if/else loop. However, it seems that TS cannot find the name of the variable *because* it's set in an if/else statement.

```ts
if (stageName === "prod") {
  let iStack = new ProdStack(app, `${BASE_NAME}-Infra-${stageName}`, iProps);
} else {
  let iStack = new InfraStack(app, `${BASE_NAME}-Infra-${stageName}`, iProps);
}
iDeploymentGroup.addStacks(iStack);
```

> Cannot find name 'iStack'.

Is this not allowed in TS? Is there a workaround?

Comment: The `var` keyword, as "old" as it is these days, is also an option as it's hoisted outside the if block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `let` variable is block-scoped so declaring it within the `if` or `else` blocks doesn't expose it outside.

There are a few work-arounds you can use such as declaring the variable above the `if..else` but personally, I'd just go with a ternary

```ts
iDeploymentGroup.addStacks(
  stageName === "prod"
    ? new ProdStack(app, `${BASE_NAME}-Infra-${stageName}`, iProps)
    : new InfraStack(app, `${BASE_NAME}-Infra-${stageName}`, iProps),
);
```

Comment: Or even ``new (stageName === "prod" ? ProdStack : InfraStack)(app, `${BASE_NAME}-Infra-${stageName}`, iProps)``